# Create Reinstallable OS ISO of RHEL with custom software

Tags: linux, iso

Currently we install our custom Linux OS(Based on RHEL) on a VMWare ESXi partition along with all required software and export it as .ova file and share with other teams which they again install on VMWare ESXi parition.

Now we have a requirement to use only bare metal without virtualization because of licensing requirements. How can create a ISO with our custom linux and all other required software to share with other teams?